# What is infinity added to itself a countably infinite number of times?

Tags: measure-theory, infinity

What is infinity added to itself a countably infinite number of times? Intuitively, it seems to me that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \infty = \infty \cdot \infty = \infty,$$

because $$ \sum_{k=1}^n \infty = n \cdot \infty = \infty,$$

but I don't know how to prove it. I asked my professor, and he said I could just use the fact that $\infty + \infty = \infty$, and I see that I can extend this by induction to the case of a finite sum, but I don't see how I can use it for the countably infinite sum.

Some context: I am trying to solve a homework exercise in my measure theory course, and I need to show that a given set function is an outer measure, but I am stuck on this step. (I also don't understand why $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$, so it'd be great if you could explain that too, but it's not my main question.)

Comment: Infinity isn't a number, so doing arithmetic operations on it like this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/TypesOfInfinity.aspx ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for the link; I  see it addresses $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$. Do you know what I could do for the countably infinite sum? Is it really equal to $\infty \cdot \infty$?

Comment: @BenSheller: That is false. Please do not make such claims on topics you are not familiar with. In measure theory, we **always** use the affinely-extended reals with the additional definition that $0·∞=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're working in the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), which are constructed by taking $\mathbb{R}$, sticking in two more elements $\infty$ and $-\infty$, and writing down a bunch of definitions stating how to do arithmetic with them.  (In particular, $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$ is a *definition* of how the operator $\cdot$ extends to using $\infty$ as an argument.)

The extended reals have a natural topology, whose exact definition is not really important here.  But for instance, you would want it to be defined in such a way that the sequence $1,2,3,\dots$ is convergent and its limit is $\infty$.

Anyway, whenever you have a space on which addition makes sense and that has a topology, a natural way to define an infinite sum
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is as the limit of the sequence partial sums $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k a_n$, provided the limit exists.  In this case, when $a_n = \infty$ for every $n$, we have $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \infty = \infty$ for every $k$.  So $\{S_k\}$ is a constant sequence; in any reasonable topology its limit should be $\infty$.  So that is how we interpret the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \infty = \infty$.

Comment: The partial sums explanation for the infinite sum makes complete sense to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @agirl: While Nate's answer is correct, I want to commend you for noticing that you cannot extend from the finite case (provable by induction) to the infinite case. Here in particular, we **chose** to define $∞·∞ = ∞$. We **could** have defined it in some other way, and simply modified the statement of theorems to cater for it.

Comment: Also note that the $∞$ in the sum limit and the $∞$ in the affinely extended reals are **not** the same, so your question of the infinite sum is actually **unrelated** to the definition of $∞·∞$.